# Editing emails doesn't affect changes

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, triggered-send

I've created a double opt-in email. And when I edit it, I'm receiving the "old" version of the email. I've tried to pause-restart the interactions > triggered emails. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pausing and restarting the triggered email isn't enough. It seems like you forgot to publish the changes. The whole workflow can be found in the documentation on the [Triggered Email Change Process](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/triggered_emails/triggered_emails_guide/triggered_email_change_process/) page.

Comment: Thank you Markus, I've just found out that and I was ready to writing the answer.

Comment: If my answer is correct, please accept it even if you found the answer yourself, so other users can easily see that there is a correct answer to your question. Thank you!